# Reorder XML Key using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I currently have a mixed-up XML payload that needs to follow the exact order of the key. To illustrate, here's the original payload:

```
<SampleMsg>
    <SampleNumber>1201</SampleNumber>
    <Dispatch>
        <ShippingDate>2021-11-12</ShippingDate>
        <Depot>SYDNEY</Depot>
        <CarrierName>ALLIED SYD</CarrierName>
    </Dispatch>
    <Cases>
        <Case>
            <CaseNumber>123ABC</CaseNumber>
            <CaseID>1</CaseID>
        </Case>
    </Cases>
</SampleMsg>
```

Here's what I want to get:

```
<SampleMsg>
    <Dispatch>
        <Depot>SYDNEY</Depot>
        <ShippingDate>2021-11-12</ShippingDate>
        <CarrierName>ALLIED SYD</CarrierName>
    </Dispatch>
    <Cases>
        <Case>
            <CaseID>1</CaseID>
            <CaseNumber>123ABC</CaseNumber>
        </Case>
    </Cases>
    <SampleNumber>1201</SampleNumber>
</SampleMsg>
```

There's no browser nor library involved, just pure javascript. Is there a way to predefine the payload structure like a java object and then transform the original payload to the formatted one? Or is there a clean code way to achieve this transformation?

I have tried researching xml-parser but every one of them uses some type of library or DOM (Which in my case, I don't have access to). I was thinking of converting to JSON and using JSON Parser, however, converting between these two formats sometimes have its setback [(read here](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html)) and it's not ideal when there's a large payload involved.

Any opinion would help and be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure why you want to order the `XML Entities`. `XML` is used to store or interchange data. No matter which order the data is stored, Once you fetch data you can sort it. Any specific reason to do this?

Comment: @BadPiggie A 12-years-old code from the progress database (which is before it supports XML Parser) is receiving this data, and as it's being used by lots of important processes, it can't be changed. I'm just trying to send it through